# Mac OSX app - build smooth UI like Transmit app

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c++

I'm working on UI for an Mac app, with lot of trying to improve for UI, but I could not make it's smooth as expected, :D. I want to build a smooth UI like Transmit app.

I also enabled core animation on all views, but it's really bad when I resize the window or moving the separator of NSSplitView.

Can anyone explain the problem here?, and is there a better approach to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Actually, the view which I'm working on, it likes Transmit app with 2 list view on left and right. I use NSSPlitView to hold that views. 
I have 2 reserved views in NSSplitView, it already layout in Interface Builder. Then I add table view for left and right.
But the NSSplitView responses too slow when I'm moving the separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: Hire a designer to make a smooth UI
**Step 2**: Learn how to work with Xcode, Interface Builder and Custom UI Elements to implement what the designer comes up with for you.
**Step 3**: Write code, test and iterate. Repeat as needed until desired results are reached.